# force file download of msword failing

Tags: php, http-headers, ms-word, download

I currently have the following:

```
if (headers_sent()) {

    echo 'HTTP header already sent';
} else {
    if (!is_file($path)) {
        header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].' 404 Not Found');
        echo 'File not found';
    } else if (!is_readable($path)) {
        header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].' 403 Forbidden');
        echo 'File not readable';
    } else {
        ob_start();
        header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].' 200 OK');
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header("Content-Type: octet-stream");
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header("Content-Length: ".filesize($path));
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($path)."\"");
        ob_clean();
        ob_flush();
        readfile($path);

        exit;
```

The above code produces a file download of the correct file name, but with a twist.

The downloaded file has some html from the download page (headers being sent incorrectly?) then later in the downloaded document there is gibberish text (ex. OJQJ^J.??. WW8Num2z0) taking up several pages.  Finally at the end of the .doc I can read some English which appears to be the correct text of the .doc, but with no formatting.

These issues persist in Chrome and Mozilla.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I began testing with a .doc that has only one line of text: "test"

The file can be opened manually from the directory in which it is uploaded to, and verified that it is not corrupt.  However, downloading this file using any of the methods recommended thus far yields several pages of gibberish text (the real file is only 1 line). The actual text of the file, which is "test", is found on the very last of the 66 pages of gibberish, and it is found in this haystack: ?test  ?"ﾰ? ﾰ?!ﾰn"ﾰn#ﾐn$ﾐn3P(20???՜.ﾓﾗ+,??՜.ﾓﾗ+,???Root Entry???????? ?F@CompObj????jOle ????????1Table????????????ﾥSummaryInformation(?????WordDocument????????????"$DocumentSummaryInformation8????????????[t????????????????

Comment: @ghoti what do you find interesting enough on it that it deserves an upvote? It's just _"here is my code, it doesn't work"_, no research effort at all is shown.

Comment: @CodeCaster - Trying to encourage a new member to be more involved with the process. An attempted solution is indeed missing, but he included his code and a decent problem description. Two out'a three seems worthy of encouragement.  I'd rather encourage than whinge and cast anonymous downvotes.

Comment: please note that my question is my current attempt. I've tried many different ways of addressing this problem and I'm sure I'd get more downvotes if I included all of THAT code as well...  This code is the first to produce results that lead me to believe that I'm close to finding a solution so this is what I chose to ask. Apologies if this is the incorrect way to go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are these?

```
    header("Content-Type: octet-stream");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
```

Trim down your code to a working example and extend it from there. You do not need to set the status code, PHP does this for you. You do not need to set the Content-length either. Sending only this should just work:

```
$path = 'foo.dat';

if (headers_sent()) {
    echo 'HTTP header already sent';
} else {
    if (!is_file($path)) {
        header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].' 404 Not Found');
        echo 'File not found';
    } else if (!is_readable($path)) {
        header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].' 403 Forbidden');
        echo 'File not readable';
    } else {
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($path)."\"");
        readfile($path);
    }
}
```

Comment: This produces the same result.  I'm thinking the problem may be with my upload procedure...  In my upload I verify that the file is of type "application/vnd.ms-office" and then I check that its a .doc - but I still don't see how it would inject all the nonsense characters into the file.

Answer (score 1):

Try this excerpt for the last `else` that is without any flushing functions

```
header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
header("Pragma: public"); 
header("Expires: 0"); 
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"); 
header("Content-Type: application/force-download"); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".basename($path));
header("Content-Description: File Transfer"); 
@readfile($path);
```

Comment: This excerpt produced the same results

Comment: Try it again (I replaced/edited the first line). What do you observe if you dot exit the script after `readfile`

Comment: I get a 404 Not Found with text: The requested URL /myproject/HTTP/1.1 200 OK was not found on this server.

Comment: I replaced header("Location: HTTP/1.1 200 OK"); with header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK") and got the same results as my initial code as far as I can tell.

Comment: Hmm.. Can you check the file permissions on the word file and see what you get when the file id chmoded to 777 and 755. And also, can you manually download the file to see that it is indeed the not corrupt file.

Comment: Having trouble chmodding... Turns out the owner and group of the file is www-data. The file permissions are 622 and 777 on the directory.  I opened the file manually from the directory and I can confirm that it is NOT corrupt.